# Crear diccionario a partir de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo esta lista:

```
laboratorio= [ [’pol’, (’hematies’, 4430000), (’basofils’, 0.5), (’calci’,
9)],
[’josep’, (’hematies’, 5130000), (’hematocrit’, 40)],
[’enrica’, (’hematies’, 4800000), (’calci’, 11.2), (’colesterol’, 2.3)],
[’paco’, (’calci’, 10.6), (’glucosa’, 0.9)],
[’lidia’, (’hematies’, 4620000), (’hematocrit’, 50), (’basofils’, 0.7)],
[’pau’, (’calci’, 10.1), (’glucosa’, 1.5), (’colesterol’, 2.5)] ]
```

A partir de esta lista necesito crear un diccionario que la clave sea nombre de la prueba y el valor una lista, es decir, a partir de la lista aneterior tengo que crear un diccionario que me quede tal que asi:

```
{’colesterol’: [2.3, 2.5], ’hematocrit’: [40.0, 50.0],
’calci’: [9, 11.2, 10.6, 10.1],
’hematies’: [4430000.0, 5130000.0, 4800000.0, 4620000.0],
’glucosa’: [0.9, 1.5], ’basofils’: [0.5, 0.7]}
```

He hecho un este bucle:

```
for i in laboratori:
    x=i[1:3]
```

Que me da como resultado esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo hago para que me quede el diccionario como me piden ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo otra solución

```
# declaración de diccionario
resultado = {}
for pruebas in laboratorio:
    for prueba in pruebas:
        # solo nos interesa aquellos datos de la lista que son tuplas
        if isinstance(prueba, tuple):
            # si en el diccionario resultante no tengo esa clave, la inicializó
            if prueba[0] not in resultado:
                resultado[prueba[0]] = []
            # agrego el valor a la clave del diccionario
            # para prueba = (’hematies’, 4430000)
            # clave: prueba[0] => 'hematies'
            # valor: prueba[1] => 4430000
            resultado[prueba[0]].append(prueba[1])
```

Como resultado obtendrías:

```
print(resultado)
{'colesterol': [2.3, 2.5], 'hematocrit': [40, 50], 'calci': [9, 11.2, 10.6, 10.1], 'hematies': [4430000, 5130000, 4800000, 4620000], 'glucosa': [0.9, 1.5], 'basofils': [0.5, 0.7]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) para crear un diccionario en el que los valores por defecto sean una lista. La ventaja es que cuando intentas acceder a la lista asociada a una clave que no existe, se crea una nueva pareja con la nueva clave y el valor por defecto (una lista) automáticamente en vez de lanzar una excepción.

Para eliminar el primer elemento puedes usar slicing como haces o usar `itertools.islice` que no crea una nueva lista como hace el slicing.

```
import collections
import itertools



laboratorio= [['pol', ('hematies', 4430000), ('basofils', 0.5), ('calci', 9)],
              ['josep', ('hematies', 5130000), ('hematocrit', 40)],
              ['enrica', ('hematies', 4800000), ('calci', 11.2), ('colesterol', 2.3)],
              ['paco', ('calci', 10.6), ('glucosa', 0.9)],
              ['lidia', ('hematies', 4620000), ('hematocrit', 50), ('basofils', 0.7)],
              ['pau', ('calci', 10.1), ('glucosa', 1.5), ('colesterol', 2.5)]
             ]

diccionario = collections.defaultdict(list)

for sublist in laboratorio:
    for key, value in itertools.islice(sublist, 1, None):
        diccionario[key].append(value)
```

La salida es:

```
>>> diccionario

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'hematies': [4430000, 5130000, 4800000, 4620000],
                             'basofils': [0.5, 0.7],
                             'calci': [9, 11.2, 10.6, 10.1],
                             'hematocrit': [40, 50],
                             'colesterol': [2.3, 2.5],
                             'glucosa': [0.9, 1.5]})
```

`defaultdict` es una subclase de `dict` y tiene todos sus métodos por tanto. Puedes usarlo como cualquier diccionario. Si por lo que sea quieres un diccionario como tal basta con hacer:

```
>>> dict(diccionario)

{'hematies': [4430000, 5130000, 4800000, 4620000],
 'basofils': [0.5, 0.7]
 'calci': [9, 11.2, 10.6, 10.1],
 'hematocrit': [40, 50],
 'colesterol': [2.3, 2.5],
 'glucosa': [0.9, 1.5]
}
```